# Extract colname from a list of unequal length of dataframes and make a colname dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, rbind

I am trying to import a bunch of csv with unequal length of columns. Some of them share the same column names others just have their own. I know how to import all of them and bind them as one dataframe and use `fill = TRUE` to deal with the unequal length. But I'd like to bind the column name of each csv into a dataframe so I can see how they are different. What's the most efficient way to do this?

```
write.csv(mtcars[, 1:5], "mtcars5.csv")
write.csv(mtcars[, 1:6], "mtcars6.csv")
write.csv(mtcars[, 1:4], "mtcars4.csv")

files_to_read <- list.files(
  path = here(),       
  pattern = ".*csv$", 
  recursive = TRUE,          
  full.names = TRUE         
)

# Bind all the csv into one but I only wanted the header
cars <- rbindlist(lapply(files_to_read, fread), fill=TRUE) 

# Maybe I should read all of them into a list first but how can I extract the colum name and bind them into a dataframe?
dflist <- lapply(files_to_read, fread)
```

Expected output something like this:

```
df1 mpg cyl disp hp         
df2 mpg cyl disp hp drat        
df3 mpg cyl disp hp drat wt
```

Comment: Would it be better to bind the file name instead of "df1", "df2" etc???

Comment: You raised a good point! @EricKrantz Is it feasible in your solution to use the filename instead of df1, df2, df3?

Comment: Yes, see update below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cars <- rbindlist(lapply(files_to_read, fread, nrows=1, header=FALSE), fill=TRUE)
cars[, 1] <- rownames(cars)
```

First column is the file index.

If you want the first column to be file names, use

```
cars[, 1] <- files_to_read
```

That will include the full path, which might not be what you want. If you want only the file name without path, use your call to `list.files` with `full.names = FALSE`, and set `cars[, 1]` equal to the results:

```
cars[, 1] <- list.files(
  path = here(),       
  pattern = ".*csv$", 
  recursive = TRUE,          
  full.names = FALSE)
```

Or you could grep it out using regex, but that seems like a lot of work if you haven't mastered regex like I haven't mastered regex.

Answer (score 1):

A shot using `purrr`

```
# Define a function read data from file - get colnames and create a data.frame
# with file_name, col_index, and col_names
get_col_df <- function(file_name) {
  data <- read.csv(file_name)
  col_names <- names(data)
  df_col_names <- tibble(data = file_name,
    col_index = seq_len(length(col_names)),
    col_names = col_names)
}

library(purrr)
col_names_df <- map_dfr(.x = files_to_read, .f = get_col_df)
```

This output

```
# A tibble: 18 x 3
   data        col_index col_names
   <chr>           <int> <chr>    
 1 mtcars4.csv         1 X        
 2 mtcars4.csv         2 mpg      
 3 mtcars4.csv         3 cyl      
 4 mtcars4.csv         4 disp     
 5 mtcars4.csv         5 hp       
 6 mtcars5.csv         1 X        
 7 mtcars5.csv         2 mpg      
 8 mtcars5.csv         3 cyl      
 9 mtcars5.csv         4 disp     
10 mtcars5.csv         5 hp       
11 mtcars5.csv         6 drat     
12 mtcars6.csv         1 X        
13 mtcars6.csv         2 mpg      
14 mtcars6.csv         3 cyl      
15 mtcars6.csv         4 disp     
16 mtcars6.csv         5 hp       
17 mtcars6.csv         6 drat     
18 mtcars6.csv         7 wt
```

And if you want to have them in rows for easier human readable

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
col_names_df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col_index, values_from = col_names)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  data        `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`  
  <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 mtcars4.csv X     mpg   cyl   disp  hp    NA    NA   
2 mtcars5.csv X     mpg   cyl   disp  hp    drat  NA   
3 mtcars6.csv X     mpg   cyl   disp  hp    drat  wt
```